# Send column index to sort function

Tags: javascript, sorting, columnsorting

Here is a function sorting 2d array by first column.

```
var a = [[12, 'AAA'], [58, 'BBB'], [28, 'CCC'],[18, 'DDD']];

console.log(a.sort(sortFunction,100));

function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return c;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

How to send a column index to function instead of hardcoded 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try to use currying:

```
sortFunction = index => (a, b) => {
    if (a[index] === b[index]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[index] < b[index]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

So usage would be something like

```
console.log(a.sort(sortFunction(1)));
```